# how to get href link from onclick function in python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I want to get href link of website form onclick function 
Here is html code in which onclick function call a website

```html
<div class="fl">
  <span class="taLnk" onclick="ta.trackEventOnPage('Eatery_Listing', 'Website', 594024, 1); ta.util.cookie.setPIDCookie(15190); ta.call('ta.util.link.targetBlank', event, this, {'aHref':'LqMWJQzZYUWJQpEcYGII26XombQQoqnQQQQoqnqgoqnQQQQoqnQQQQoqnQQQQoqnqgoqnQQQQoqnQQuuuQQoqnQQQQoqnxioqnQQQQoqnQQ2EisSMVCnVcJQQoqnQQQQoqnxioqnQQQQoqnQQniaQQoqnQQQQoqnqgoqnQQQQoqnQQWJQzhYMJkH3KHVAdJJH3VVdB', 'isAsdf':true})">Website</span> 
</div>
```

Normaly i use this code to get href link from any span or element

```js
geturl = soup.findsoup("span", {"class": "taLnk"})
for link in geturl:
  hreflink = link.get("href")
  print(hreflink)
```

But in this case there is no way to directly call href because href exist in onclick function

Please help me what to do now

Comment: do you want to extract data located in `aHref`

Comment: yes i want to extract data located in aHref. This data contain link of website. and also how to generate website link from this data please help me if you can @akash karothiya

Comment: `aHref` data you can extract easily, using `bs4` and `regex`

Comment: Kindly can you give me some code or example how to do it

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly parse `aHref` attribute, you need to extract `onclick` first.

```
>>> import re
>>> data = soup.select('.taLnk')[0].get('onclick')
>>> href = re.search(r"(?is)'aHref':'(.*?)'",str(data)).group(1)
'LqMWJQzZYUWJQpEcYGII26XombQQoqnQQQQoqnqgoqnQQQQoqnQQQQoqnQQQQoqnqgoqnQQQQoqnQQuuuQQoqnQQQQoqnxioqnQQQQoqnQQ2EisSMVCnVcJQQoqnQQQQoqnxioqnQQQQoqnQQniaQQoqnQQQQoqnqgoqnQQQQoqnQQWJQzhYMJkH3KHVAdJJH3VVdB'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex with bs4, selecting the span with the class taLnk and the *onclick* attribute starting with *ta.trackEventOnPage*:

```
h = """<div class="fl">
  <span class="taLnk" onclick="ta.trackEventOnPage('Eatery_Listing', 'Website', 594024, 1); ta.util.cookie.setPIDCookie(15190); ta.call('ta.util.link.targetBlank', event, this, {'aHref':'LqMWJQzZYUWJQpEcYGII26XombQQoqnQQQQoqnqgoqnQQQQoqnQQQQoqnQQQQoqnqgoqnQQQQoqnQQuuuQQoqnQQQQoqnxioqnQQQQoqnQQ2EisSMVCnVcJQQoqnQQQQoqnxioqnQQQQoqnQQniaQQoqnQQQQoqnqgoqnQQQQoqnQQWJQzhYMJkH3KHVAdJJH3VVdB', 'isAsdf':true})">Website</span>
</div>"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
soup = BeautifulSoup(h)

data = soup.select_one("span.taLnk[onclick^=ta.trackEventOnPage]")["onclick"]
print(re.search("'aHref':'(.*?)'", data).group(1))
```