# BeautifulSoup: extract an attribute from an element?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I've tried to look this up on Stackoverflow but I couldn't make it fit into my code. Perhaps someone can help me on this?

I am trying to get the 'team1', 'team2' and 'bettext'-attributes from this HTML:

```html
<table class="sportbet_extra_list_table" id="mc-ga312004790">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="sportbet_extra_c0"></td>
            <td class="sportbet_extra_c1"><span>
                <a class="combi_1"></a>
                Hvem vinder kampen?                            </span></td>
            <td class="sportbet_extra_c2">
                   <div id="mc-ti312004790_1" class="js-ti312004790_1 sportbet_extra_rate_content" onclick="Bettingslip.addBet({type: 'N', team1: 'Rusland', team2: 'Saudi Arabien', bettext: 'Hvem vinder kampen?', combi_cat: 1, sub_group: 0, game: 312004790, groupId:461392, leagueId:30124, odd: 138, odd_id: 312004790, tiptext: '1', tip: 1, betstyle: 2224})">
                    <div class="sportbet_content_rate_left">1</div>
                    <div class="sportbet_content_rate_right">1,38</div>
                </div>
    
            </td>
```

So far this code is what I am using to extract information from sportbet_extra_list_table:

```
    REQUEST = requests.get('https://www.cashpoint.dk/en/? 
              r=bets/xtra&group=461392&game=312004790').text
    SOUP = BeautifulSoup(REQUEST, 'lxml')
    # find_all to extract all
    SCRAPE = SOUP.find('table', class_='sportbet_extra_list_table')

    for CLEAN in SCRAPE:
        CLEANER = BeautifulSoup(str(CLEAN), 'lxml').text
        STRIP = " ".join(line.strip() for line in CLEANER.split("\n"))
        print(STRIP)
```

I was trying to add

```
SOUP.find('table', class_='sportbet_extra_list_table', attrs={"onclick": "team1"})
```

But it didn't work

Comment: Maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39289206/how-to-get-href-link-from-onclick-function-in-python/39290184

Comment: Thank you for the link. I have a hard time trying to convert it to my situation though :( I'll try look into 're' if I get no other replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`demjson.decode()`](http://deron.meranda.us/python/demjson/demjson-2.2.3/docs/demjson.html#-decode) to convert raw JavaScript objects into Python dictionaries. It makes getting specific data about the bet much easier.

**Code:**

```
import re
import demjson
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.cashpoint.dk/en/'
                 '?r=bets/xtra'
                 '&group=461392'
                 '&game=312004790')

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
tables = soup.select('table.sportbet_extra_list_table')

for table in tables:
    fields = table.select('.sportbet_extra_rate_content')
    for field in fields:
        js_obj = re.search('{.+}', field['onclick']).group()
        bet = demjson.decode(js_obj)
        print((bet['team1'], bet['team2'], bet['bettext'], bet['tiptext'], bet['tip']))
```

**Output:**

```
('Rusland', 'Saudi Arabien', 'Hvem vinder kampen?', '1', 1)
('Rusland', 'Saudi Arabien', 'Hvem vinder kampen?', 'X', 3)
('Rusland', 'Saudi Arabien', 'Hvem vinder kampen?', '2', 2)
('Rusland', 'Saudi Arabien', 'Dobbeltchance', '1x', 1)
...
('Rusland', 'Saudi Arabien', 'Scorer i begge HL', 'B', 2)
```

Comment: I'm gonna go with TopTo's reply. Thank you for taking your time to help out!

Comment: @ChristianHandest what's wrong with this answer? It's clean and gives you access to all the info about the bet. Topto's code is hard to understand with all these nested `split()` calls + there is a lot of code duplication out there.

Comment: After testing both yours, N3RO's and TopTo's code it ended up with I am using N3RO's code mainly and yours too. N3RO's code explained a bit more indepth on how to navigate with attrs and he used my code. So I went with this and now I am sitting and learning from this.
But when I get more in depth with my own code now and moving forward I may well end up using yours anyway as it gives me a nice json table I can extract later and if so I'll change "solved" pos. Again thank you so much, Jatimir!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following to get the output the way you have mentioned in your post:

```
import json
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.cashpoint.dk/en/?r=bets/xtra&group=461392&game=312004790"

res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')

dataset = []
for items in soup.select("#container_xtra [id^='mc-ti']"):
    d = {}
    data = items.get("onclick").split("Bettingslip.addBet(")[1].split(")")[0]

    d['team1'] = data.split("team1:")[1].split(",")[0].split("'")[1].split("'")[0]
    d['team2'] = data.split("team2:")[1].split(",")[0].split("'")[1].split("'")[0]
    d['bettext'] = data.split("bettext:")[1].split(",")[0].split("'")[1].split("'")[0]
    if d not in dataset:
        dataset.append(d)

print(json.dumps(dataset,indent=4))
```

Partial result:

```
[
    {
        "team1": "Rusland",
        "team2": "Saudi Arabien",
        "bettext": "Hvem vinder kampen?"
    },
    {
        "team1": "Rusland",
        "team2": "Saudi Arabien",
        "bettext": "Dobbeltchance"
    },
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution to your problem :

```
SCRAPE = SOUP.find('table', class_='sportbet_extra_list_table')
# Get the content of the onclick attribute using ['onclick']
SCRAPE = SCRAPE.find('div', id="mc-ti312004790_1")['onclick']
# Now separate every variable in it
attrs = SCRAPE.split(',')
# Retrieve what you want
team1 = attrs[1].split(':')[1].replace(' ', '').replace('\'', '')
team2 = attrs[2].split(':')[1].replace(' ', '').replace('\'', '')
bettext = attrs[3].split(':')[1].replace(' ', '').replace('\'', '')

print(team1)
print(team2)
print(bettext)
```

It outputs :

> Rusland
>
> SaudiArabien
>
> Hvemvinderkampen?

The attrs variable looks like this :

> ["Bettingslip.addBet({type: 'N'", " team1: 'Rusland'", " team2: 'Saudi Arabien'", " bettext: 'Hvem vinder kampen?'", ' combi_cat: 1', ' sub_group: 0',
>   ' game: 312004790', ' groupId:461392', ' leagueId:30124', ' odd: 138', ' odd_id: 312004790', " tiptext: '1'", ' tip: 1', ' betstyle: 2224})']

The attrs[1] variable is :

> " team1: 'Rusland'"

doing .split(':') gives :

> ['" team1", " 'Rusland'"]

to get the team1 name we will take attrs[1].split(':')[1], it gives :

> " 'Rusland'"

Doing .replace(' ', '') remove the spaces, and doing .replace('\'', '') removes the "'".

Comment: Exactly what I needed with indepth explainations of what's happening. Thank you so much, N3RO!

Comment: You're welcome @ChristianHandest, good luck for your project ! :)